# Frame size is changed after numpy typecasting

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

**Frame Display got stretched after changing dtpye to np.unit8**

```
Y = array.array('f')
yy = np.array(Y)    
bb=yy + (1.7790 * (uu - 128));
bb=np.reshape(bb, (672,1280))
bb.dtype=np.uint8 *without this frame size is fine*
cv2.imshow('Image', bb)
```

Comment: Frame Length got stretched after typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
bb.dtype=np.uint8
```

to:

```
bb_new = np.array(bb,dtype=np.uint8)
```